# Segmantation fault in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

i am trying to find factorial by recursively.My function works but why i recieve  "segmenatation fault (core dumped)" when i input -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fak(int number);

int main(){

    int i;
    printf("give me an integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    printf("factorial: %d\n",fak(i));

    return 0;
}

int fak(int number){

    if(number == 1 || number == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    return number * fak(number - 1);
}
```

Comment: Think about it. How/when does the recursion stop with that input?

Comment: You are getting the name of this website.  A **StackOverflow** error.

Comment: Paul I need you address, sending you flowers now :D

Comment: Amazing how the reason is the name of this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question: you will get a stack overflow because your recursive method will never end normally (see all the comments).

If you put in -1, the method will be called again with -2.
It depends on your stack-size when it will crash.

You can change your condition to:

```
if(number <= 1){
    return 1;
}
```

Besides of that: the factorial of -1 doesn't exist.